# Como formatar tags html com javascipt

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço, para que quando alguém digitar uma tag html, no meu editor online, o javascript defina uma cor para aquela tag ?
Um exemplo seria:

```
< html>

//Essa tag teria sua cor mudada por uma função

function Tag(){

//A função tag ao ser chamada iria setar uma cor

}
```

Comment: Tem muita coisa pronta já para fazer isso. Acho que o nome disso é hightlighter

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_syntax_highlight.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomento a biblioteca javascript [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) (*open-source*):

- 176 linguagens e 79 estilos
- Detecção automática de linguagem
- Estilizador de códigos Multi-Linguagem
- Disponível para node.js
- Funciona com qualquer marcação
- Compatível com qualquer biblioteca javascript

---

Segue um exemplo utilizando **highlight.js** para **javascript** e **css** com o tema **atelier-forest-dark**:

```js
//Função que inicializa o highlight.js para personalização das cores do código
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/styles/atelier-forest-dark.min.css">
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>

Exemplo estilo para códigos <strong>javascript</strong>:

<pre>
<code class="javascript">function funcaoTeste(block, cls) {
    try {
      if (cls.search(/\bno\-highlight\b/) != -1)
        return process(block, true, 0x0F) +
               ` class="${cls}"`;
    } catch (e) {
      /* comentário: captura da exceção */
    }
  }
</code>
</pre> 

Exemplo estilo para códigos <strong>css</strong>:

<pre>
<code class="css">@font-face {
  font-family: Chunkfive; src: url('Chunkfive.otf');
}

body, .textoUsuario {
  color: #F0F0F0; background: #600;
  font-family: Chunkfive, sans;
}

@import url(estilo.css);
@media print {
  a[href^=http]::after {
    content: attr(href)
  }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

---

- **Documentação completa:** http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- **Exemplos utilizando várias linguagens:**
  https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/
- **Código fonte do projeto highlight.js:**
  https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js
- **Estilos disponíveis:** http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/styles/

Answer (score 0):

É possivel fazer isso pelo atributo `contenteditable="true"` em uma div, por exemplo.

[**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cfGzS3dr7k2rMTrV69e9?p=preview)